# I made an astable multivibrator, connected it to a transformer, and I really don't know what's going on

Tags: high-voltage, multivibrator

I tried to drive some H-bridges with the multivibrator circuit to drive a small 1:25 SMD transformer to make hv for geiger tubes. My results were slightly underwhelming, so I started to do random stuff and i started connecting the multivibrator outputs directly to the transformer.
[image]
At first nothing happened, then I turned off the power supply then back, and then I saw a peak to peak  400v sinewave on the scope, with a much higher frequency than the multivibrator worked before.  Then I turned it off and turned it on and nothing again. And I've done this a few times, and it seems to be completely random when it works and when it doesn't. If it works it uses less current around 40 mA. If it's not 70 mA. Also, if i connect the psu wires to the circuit by hand the circuit mostly fails to work, but when using the psu main switch it's working much more often.

[image]

My question is why does this circuit work the way it is and why does it sometimes fail? It would be very useful information to know, because it would be perfect for my usecase.

Comment: Sounds like you created something similar to a Royer oscillator. (If that primary has a centre tap, I'd suggest you look at them anyway)

Comment: Since you have an oscilloscope you can measure the voltages on your circuit. My guess is when powered, the operating point is way off due to the current through the transformer and the drop across the 220R resistors. So the multivibrator doesn’t work. As the voltage chsnges, so does the operating point. You then have a window of operation as the voltage decreases. With no part numbers or the vcc voltage, we’re only guessing. For generating high voltage for gm tubes you’ll normally see a flyback or ringing choke converter. These require only one switching element.

Comment: Add a part number for the coil and specify your Vcc voltage, as well. As Andy says, that's likely not the schematic you want, though that doesn't mean it can't work. Finally, the higher frequency may be due to an unwanted oscillation from parasitics and the coil.

Comment: kecske3141593, You aren't responding here, yet. But there are lots of problems with your concept. One is that you are straddling a primary across the two collectors. While they may actively pull-down, the pull-up is a simple resistor. This isn't a very good way to use a transformer, even assuming the rest worked ok. Another is that you probably want a center-tapped primary if you are using a transformer so you can alternate sides if you want to use 50% duty. And if you use an inductor, instead, then the duty cycle is related to the voltage ratios.

Comment: When it works (simulation), here is an example of what one gets: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x5LC.png

Answer (score 1):

> *My question is why does this circuit work the way it is and why does
> it sometimes fail?*

It sometimes works (and fails at other times) because the astable multivibrator circuit isn't really fit-for-purpose in both its jobs i.e. : -

(1) Being an oscillator AND

(2) Driving a fairly heavy load like the transformer.

The output voltage at the collector isn't a hard-nosed voltage that can sustain it's output level under fairly heavy loads; it is a fairly feeble output that is "just about" working in your scenario. If you did an analysis on the collector output voltage, you would find that it looks like a voltage source in series with the collector load resistors (220 Ω) and, if this is loaded by too much current, that collector voltage would drop and, the oscillator would fail to er... oscillate.

You are on that cusp it seems.

Maybe add emitter follower BJTs to buffer the output before it feeds the transformer. Keep the same astable circuit because that looks sound. The BJT buffers will provide a much lower output impedance to the transformer AND isolate that heavy load current from the astable collectors.

The next problem will be too much AC output voltage so, you might choose to lower the supply voltage to reduce the drive level or, put series resistors in the primary feed of the transformer.